# Codable. How decode dictionary to property

Tags: swift, codable

I get a response from the server of this type, where the name of the pair is the key:

```
{
    "BTC_BCN":{
        "last":"0.00000057",
        "percentChange":"0.03636363",
        "baseVolume":"47.08463318"
    },
    "BTC_BELA":{
        "last":"0.00001281",
        "percentChange":"0.07376362",
        "baseVolume":"5.46595029"
    }
}
```

How can I decode it to a structure where the property name is the key from json:

```
struct Pair: Codable {
    let name: String // need to put the name of the pair ("BTC_BCN")
    let last: String
    let percentChange: String
    let baseVolume: String
}
```

Comment: Did you try implementing custom encoder and decoder? This might help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: For an almost exact parallel, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967696/341994. Instead of making a "flat" single struct, I turn the unknown keys into dictionary keys and put the deeper struct as the value, so it is hierarchical just like your JSON. But that's a minor difference.

Comment: That's what I finally came up with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186681/9682968